# shuffle values(text) within same row in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet with data, just want to shuffle Cell A values. After"," values shuffle like in cell B. I know the way to shuffle values from different cells. but dont know how to do within same row

```
Row No.  |     A                                             B
 1       |  Text One, Text Two, Text Three        Text two text one text three
 2       |  Text name, Text You, Text Me          Text Me Text name Text You
 3       |  Text 1, Text 2, Text 3                Text 1 Text 3 Text 2
```

Comment: Use vba to split and randomize. That's your question isn't it?

Comment: Your data has a normalization problem, and it will be relatively difficult to do what you want using pure Excel formulas.  Rather, you should store each CSV value in a separate cell.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  yes i know that at end this is the final salutation that's why i post here if their is any way to do this within row . anyways thanks for your help

Comment: @Jeeped for that i can use text to column tool and then formula to randomize, yes i can also use vba. but just want to find way if i can manage it within row.

Comment: @deccc are you saying you want to randomize the "words" within a single cell, and without using VBA?

Comment: @ashleedawg no im not saying that ...i know its not possible without vba and also im  new to excel so i need help, so thats why i ask here. if any formula that would grate but vba also ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VBA function to randomize the "words" within a cell.  You didn't explicitly mention this but it looks like you also need to change the delimiters from commas to spaces during the process.

This is possible with VBA, using a *whole bunch* of helper columns, but not recommended.  This VBA function will do the trick:

```
Function randomizeSentence(sentenceIn As String, _
    Optional delimIn As String = ",",Optional delimOut As String = " ") As String

    Dim strIn As String, strOut As String, arr, occ As Long
    strIn = sentenceIn 'put input in variable

    Do
        strIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(strIn) 'remove whitespace
        arr = Split(strIn, delimIn) 'separate words into array based on spaces
        occ = Int(Rnd() * (UBound(arr) + 1)) 'get a random word
        strOut = strOut & Trim(arr(occ)) & delimOut 'append word to output
        strIn = Trim(Replace(strIn, arr(occ), "")) 'remove word from input
        If Right(strIn, 1) = delimIn Then strIn = Trim(Left(strIn, Len(strIn)-1))

    Loop While Len(Replace(strIn, delimIn, "")) > 0 'go until only delim's left

    randomizeSentence = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(strOut)

End Function
```

This can be used as a worksheet function:

```
=randomizeSentence(A1)
```

or as a VBA function:

```
MsgBox randomizeSentence(Range("A1"))
'or
MsgBox randomizeSentence("abc, def, ghi")
```

---

**Delimiter parameters:**

Note that the function accepts alternate "input" & "output" delimiters to be specified as parameters, like:

```
randomizeSentence ( inputString, inputDelimiter, outputDelimiter )
```

...however if they are not specified they default to what you used in your example.
(Input Delimiter = comma; Output Delimiter = space)

---

**Re-randomizing:**

Note that this function will **not** automatically re-calculate in a normal Excel automatic **or** manual re-calculation (ie., <kbd>F9</kbd>).

<sup>*(There's a name for that type of function but it elsudes me at the moment; maybe someone can remind me?!  [WEBSERVICE] is another example.)*</sup>

It **will**, however, re-calculate (re-randomize) when you enter the formula, or if you change the value in the cell it's referring to, or if you click on the cell and hit <kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <del>or with VBA method `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`</del>.

***Edit:*** a "less expensive" method of forcing the function to recalculate on every worksheet change would be to add `Application.Volatile` within the function. <sup><sub>(Thanks @QHarr!)</sub></sup>

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Rnd` Function** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rnd-function)
- MSDN : [**`Split` Function** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)
- MSDN : [**`Application.CalculateFullRebuild` Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculatefullrebuild-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Application.Volatile` Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel)
- DecisionModels.com : **[Volatile Excel Functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm)**

Comment: volatile function? And does it needs something as expensive as FullReBuild? (Genuine question)

Comment: @ashleedawg thanks for help and your time, im out of city and dont carry my laptop with me, will update you soon. thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @QHarr - no, it doesn't require `CalculateFullRebuild` now that you reminded me what the type of function is called; `Application.Volatile` (within the function) is a better choice.  Interesting overview on volatile functions [here](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm), such as which built-in functions are/are not volatile, and which ones have changed over time.

Comment: @ashleedawg You are a mine of good information :-) I have seen this reference before. It is really rather good.

Comment: @QHarr  I'm not as much of a *mine of information* as much as I'm good at *mining information*.  I believe "Effective Googling" should be the first module of any Coding 101 class.   :-)

Comment: there is also a URL that allows you to find cache google pages but I can't remember it so resorting to WayBack Machine at present to find old pages. In a moment of google-fu I have found it again...http://webcache.googleusercontent.com

Comment: @QHarr You're probably referring to the `cache:` tag that can be added to Google searches (that tip and more [here](https://www.lifewire.com/google-searches-and-power-tricks-4093009)).  My personal most-used Google trick when looking for coding-related stuff it to use the *Verbatim* option so Google doesn't try to correct the spelling/grammar of coding keywords.  My Google search toolbar buttons points at [`https://www.google.ca/?tbs=li:1`](https://www.google.ca/?tbs=li:1); the `tbs=li:1` forces Verbatim mode. (Oddly, it doesn't seem to work the same with `google.com` or other countries.)